# Perl with Javascript (Perlscript)

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

I'm to trying for Perl CGI with Javascript. It is difficult for me.

Try:

```
    if ($lqcgi->param('sel_cl')){
        $selected_action = $lqcgi->param('sel_cl');
        print "<TR><script> document.write("<button type=\"button\" id=\"delete\">Delete</button>")</script>$line $ssh_command_flow User: $ENV{ REMOTE_USER }</TR>\n";
    }
```

I don't know whether that's correct or wrong. Pls help me. Thank you.

Comment: Impossible to tell with what you've given us. We need more detail on what you're doing, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's also helpful to ask a question. :)

Comment: Ok. Example: 

`if ($lqcgi->param('sel_cl')){
   $selected_action = $lqcgi->param('sel_cl');
   print "<TR><TD>$line $ssh_command_flow User: $ENV{ REMOTE_USER }</TD></TR>\n";
   print "<TD><script><button type=\"button\" id=\"delete\">Delete</button></script></TD></TR>\n";
  }`

Comment: That's the same code you have in your question. But you have still not asked a question.

Comment: Please edit you question to add more information. In particular, tell us what unexpected behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: HTML nested inside JavaScript nested inside (invalid!) HTML nested in Perl. Oh the pain. The pain. Use [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples) not `document.write`. Use [templates](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Toolkit) not string literals. [Avoid CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE). Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know what your problem is as you haven't actually asked a question. But I'll just point out that you have a double-quoted string that contains double quote characters. And not all of them are escaped correctly.

Perl has the `qq(...)` operator which makes it easier to produce double-quoted strings that contain double quote characters.

```
if ($lqcgi->param('sel_cl')){
    $selected_action = $lqcgi->param('sel_cl');
    print qq(<TR><script> document.write("<button type=\\"button\\" id=\\"delete\\">Delete</button>")</script>$line $ssh_command_flow User: $ENV{ REMOTE_USER }</TR>\n);
}
```

**Update:** You also need to double the "`\`"s so that they get passed through to the Javascript.

Comment: Won't the ``\`` characters be treated as Perl escape characters when they are intended to be JavaScript escape characters?

Comment: Absolutely. Fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out.